# jquery load specific html content from child element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, windows

Hi everyone im trying to get the specific element from my other website with jquery unfortunately it didnt work with the code that i search. hope you understand what i am trying to achieved sorry for my english

Here's My Code

mysampleurl.com/postpageslist

```
<html>
<div class="postoutercontainer">
    <div class="postouter">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="postTITLE">
                <a href="#samplepost">POST1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="postoutercontainer">
    <div class="postouter">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="postTITLE">
                <a href="#samplepost">POST2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="postoutercontainer">
    <div class="postouter">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="postTITLE">
                <a href="#samplepost">POST3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="postoutercontainer">
    <div class="postouter">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="postTITLE">
                <a href="#samplepost">POST4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="postoutercontainer">
    <div class="postouter">
        <div class="post">
            <div class="postTITLE">
                <a href="#samplepost">POST5</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

mysampleurl.com/targetpage

```
<div id="samplediv">
    
 
<script>
  
  $('#samplediv').load('/postpageslist .postoutercontainer p:lt(POST3)');
  
</script>
```

SOLVED i just use :contains(POST3)

WORKING CODE

```
$('#samplediv').load('/postpageslist .postoutercontainer:contains(POST3)');
```

Comment: `load()` doesn't allow you to get specific elements, it returns the entire content

Comment: do you have any other option that i could use

Comment: actually, I was completely wrong... Looks like it can be done using `load()` as you approached

Comment: problem could be `:lt()` syntax, you're not passing a numeric index to it. Please try `$('#samplediv').load('/postpageslist .postoutercontainer:lt(3)');`

Comment: i tried it, it displays 3 .postoutercontainer, when i try (2) it displays 2 .postoutercontainer, also as (1) it displays 1 .postoutercontainer and not the specific div that i target

Comment: Hi thanks for your time i already solve my problem i just use :contains(POST3) and it worked! 

$('#samplediv').load('/postpageslist .postoutercontainer:contains(POST3)');